# Facebook Apps Performance - Insights

Tags: performance, facebook-insights

How to i know my apps perfomance and page loding ratings in Insights.

i referred [App on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#perf) tutorial,

through that i used following methods in my code,

`FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading` ,   `FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource` and

`FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.setCollectionMode`.

My Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>     
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({ appId: '*****', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true }); 

   FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.setCollectionMode(FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.COLLECT_AUTOMATIC);   
   FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource("http://example.com/fb/js/fb.js");
   FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource("http://example.com/fb/css/fb.css");
   FB.Canvas.Prefetcher.addStaticResource("http://example.com/fb/css/style.css");       

   FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading();
 };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

when i see in insight dashboard it showing like,
[image]

is there any wrong.. why its not showing... have i call that methods in correct place..?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Graph API Explorer to ensure that they're working in that respect?

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2439131959%2Fstaticresources

Use the dropdown at the top right to select your application (you should be logged in as the owner of the app you want to test); your selection will replace the &path=nnn in the input field to the right of the GET request in the explorer.

Make sure that you're not getting an error response from Facebook. This is how I've checked my prefetch methods; I haven't used the insights dashboard yet.